# Fast way to build a table that refers to most recent addition?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I'm trying to construct a large table where new entries depend on the most recent entries. It's quite slow: takes 2 mins and I'm embedding this into a function that does it repeatedly so any reduction in time is a big savings. I think this issue is with "AppendTo" and I've seen repeated references on here to use Reap/Sow, but I'm having trouble implementing that because the next entries in the table are conditional on the previous. Here is an example of the code I'm working with right now.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

TransMark = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 7}, {j, 7}]; (*Just an example of a similar matrix to what I have*)

RandDraw = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 10000}, {j, 576}];

WorkerMat = Table[{{2, 1}}, {10000}]; 

Timing[Do[
   If[RandDraw[[i, j]] <= 
     TransMark[[All, 1]][[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]]]],
    If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 1, 
     Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
    AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {1, Tenure}],
    If[RandDraw[[i, j]] <= 
      TransMark[[All, 2]][[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]]]],
     If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 2, 
      Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
     AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {2, Tenure}],
     If[RandDraw[[i, j]] <= 
       TransMark[[All, 3]][[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]]]],
      If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 3, 
       Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
      AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {3, Tenure}],
      If[RandDraw[[i, j]] <= 
        TransMark[[All, 4]][[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]]]],
       If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 4, 
        Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
       AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {4, Tenure}],
       If[
        RandDraw[[i, j]] <= 
         TransMark[[All, 5]][[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]]]],
        If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 5, 
         Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
        AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {5, Tenure}],
        If[
         RandDraw[[i, j]] <= 
          TransMark[[All, 6]][[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]]]],
         If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 6, 
          Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
         AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {6, Tenure}],
         If[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[1]] == 7, 
          Tenure = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]][[2]] + 1, Tenure = 1];
         AppendTo[WorkerMat[[i]], {7, Tenure}];]]]]]] , {j, 1, 
    576}, {i, 1, 10000}];
 ];
```

Which takes over 2 mins on my machine.
My apologies if this is a repeat question, but I've been looking for a similar post for many hours and have not discovered one.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: Can you construct a *minimal* working example that illustrates your issue?  I suspect the essence of the problem can be described with much less code.

Comment: [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html), [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) and their "See Also"s are probably good places to start looking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues with your code: First, it is very procedural with lots of `If` statements. Mathematica is slow at processing procedural code. Good news: Procedural code in Mathematica can usually be compiled with `Compile` in order to speed up the execution.

The second and major flaw of your code however is that you use `AppendTo` quite often. Every time you use it, a list has to be copied which makes the code very memory bound and of computational complexity $O(N^2)$ for a list with $N$ elements (and thus slow).

Fortunately, the size of `WorkingMat` is known right from the start and `Last[WorkerMat[[i]]]` refers to `WorkerMat[[i,j]]` and `Append[Last[WorkerMat[[i]]],value]` can be replaced by `WorkerMat[[i,j+1]] = value`. Moreover, one can make the `j`-loop the outer loop and parallelize it. Afterwards, one obtains a code which is nicely compilable. Replacing the nested `If` construction by a lookup for the first entry in a certain list which is greater or equal a certain value, the result is the `CompiledFunction` `cf` below (I am skipping a significant amount of refactorization steps here.)

```
cf = Compile[{{rand, _Real, 1}, {TransMark, _Real, 2}},
  Block[{r, a, b, k},
   a = Table[0, {i, 1, Length[rand] + 1}, {j, 1, 2}];
   a[[1, 1]] = 2;
   a[[1, 2]] = 1;
   Do[
    r = Compile`GetElement[rand, j];
    b = Compile`GetElement[a, j, 1];
    k = 1;
    While[r > Compile`GetElement[TransMark, b, k] && k < 7, k++];
    a[[j + 1, 1]] = k;
    a[[j + 1, 2]] = If[b == k, Compile`GetElement[a, j, 2] + 1, 1];
    , {j, 1, Length[rand]}];
   a
   ],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True,
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

Btw., the `` Compile`GetElement `` statements in the code above are read-only instructions that replace `Part`. I think it instructs the C code generator to skip certain bound checks. This can improve the performance considerably but makes it less "safe".

Generating some data...

```
SeedRandom[1234];
TransMark = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {7, 7}];
n = 10000;
m = 576;
RandDraw = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, m}];
```

... and running the code on the data

```
WorkerMat2 = cf[RandDraw, TransMark]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
```

> 0.05216

Your original code took about 86 seconds on my machine, so that's a speed-up of factor 1600 or so.

Answer (score 1):

This is substantially faster and might be equivalent. If it is not, I may well have made mistakes in translating and, as was noted, a minimal working example is a useful commodity.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
TransMark = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {7, 7}];
maxi = 10000;
maxj = 576;
RandDraw = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {maxi, maxj}];
WorkerMat = Table[{{2, 1}}, {maxi}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 wm2 = Table[
   last = Last[WorkerMat[[i]]];
   rndi = RandDraw[[i]];
   ltable = Table[
     rndij = rndi[[j]];
     {l1, l2} = last;
     tm1 = TransMark[[l1]];
     tenure = 1;
     Which[rndij <= tm1[[1]], k = 1,
      rndij <= tm1[[2]], k = 2,
      rndij <= tm1[[3]], k = 3,
      rndij <= tm1[[4]], k = 4,
      rndij <= tm1[[5]], k = 5,
      rndij <= tm1[[6]], k = 6,
      True, k = 7
      ];
     If[l1 == k, tenure = l2 + 1];
     last = {k, tenure}
     , {j, maxj}];
   Developer`ToPackedArray[ltable]
   , {i, maxi}];]

(* Out[374]= {27.892029, Null} *)

wm3 = Join[WorkerMat, wm2, 2];
```

That last should give the original result.

I'm sure a further speed gain could be had using `Compile`.